# How to create custom Object Library items?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, custom-component, iboutlet, nssplitview

I have written a custom view class that has two sub views, very similar to NSSplitView. I would like my new class to show up with two sub views when it is used in interface builder. The two subviews can be any NSView, but need to be specified by the developer.

How can I add my class to the Object Library?

How do I specify to IB that my class that it has two required subviews (IBoutlets)?

Thanks in advance,
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond making the subview properties IBOutlets, it's not possible to customize the way Interface Builder presents custom classes in Xcode 4. It used to be possible in (standalone) Interface Builder before Xcode 4, but that functionality was removed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess I can assert that the two views are not nil at runtime.

Comment: Yes, that's a decent approach. Just make sure you log a good, descriptive statement when the assertion fails so that it's easy to figure out what's wrong.